# simctl | fbsimctl : Simulator becomes unresponsive if booted after shutdown command

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, simctl

I'm trying to achieve some automation for iOS simulators. I'm facing a strange issue that I'm not able to understand. Precisely following is my scenario:

1. I create a simulator using command: `xcrun simctl create "iPhone 8 Plus"`
2. I rename my newly created simulator: `xcrun simctl rename <udid> my-new-iphone-8-plus`
3. I boot my simulator: `xcrun simctl boot <udid>`
4. I open the simulator app: `open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/`. At this point the simulator app is up and running and I can fully interact with the simulator.
5. I shutdown the simulator: `xcrun simctl shutdown <udid>`. At this point the simulator gets shutdown but the simulator app is still running, which makes sense because I may be running more than one simulators simultaneously.
6. I boot the shutdown simulator again: `xcrun simctl boot <udid>`. At this point the simulator launches quickly. Neither the boot screen appears nor any loading indicator, as it appeared the first time I launched it.

At this moment the simulator is not responsive to my touch. It seems like it's stuck. The command returns successfully and doesn't return any errors.

I have tried the same thing using `fbsimctl` as well. I faced the same issue. Also tried with multiple simulators.

***ONE IMPORTANT THING:*** When I close the simulator manually by selecting the desired simulator window and then do `CMD + W` or close it from the top left red close button and then boot it again from command line it surprisingly works fine.

***OBJECTIVE:*** When the simulator is booted after shutdown using command line, the simulator should be responsive like it was before.

I tried other things as well, like killing process using `pid`. It didn't help.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known bug

Comment: Yep seems so. Now I’m using headless approach and launching sims in background as I’ll be interacting with them using a web interface and a video stream